# cURL php request to ASP

Tags: php, asp.net

I am trying to send a post value to my asp file. The issue is I have tested using POSTMAN tool to check if my request and response is correct. But when I try to send the request using php it keep returning false. I cant seem to correct the issue. I have searched stackoverflow how to make cURL request using POST but all return false as response.

I should be receiving "ALLOWED" value as response in php but all i am getting "false" value.

**PHP**

```
$EmployeeNo = "BCB0001";
$PASSWORD = "3333";


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, MY-ASP-URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
         http_build_query(array('EmployeeNo' => $EmployeeNo, 'PASSWORD' => $PASSWORD)));

// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $server_output;

curl_close ($ch);
```

**ASP**

```
ID = Request("EmployeeNo")
Password = Request("PASSWORD")

Dim ALLOWED,NOT_ALLOWED
ALLOWED = 1
NOT_ALLOWED = 0

If ID = "" Then 
    Response.Write(NOT_ALLOWED)
Elseif getData("UserID","tablenane","UserID",ID) <> "" then 

    Dim chkID,chkPass'Edit By Shun
    chkID = getData("UserID","tablenane","UserID",ID)
    chkPass = getData("Password","tablenane","UserID",ID)

    if chkID = ID AND AESDecrypt(chkPass,theAESKey.AESKey) = Password then 'verify password
        Response.Write(ALLOWED)
    else
        Response.Write(NOT_ALLOWED)
    end if
end if
```

Comment: Don't use AES to secure passwords in your database! It's only 1 step better from plaintext, and still far insecure. You should be using bcrypt or similar hashing functions (One way!)

Comment: Right now my issue is concerning the return value from asp to php. Why does it return false on $response = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: Have you made sure you are receiving ID and Password correctly? By logging or returning the same as response before running any if conditions. That's the first thing I would do to debug.

Comment: @FleminAdambukulam May I know how to debug if the code is not located in my computer. I know we can debug using Visual Studio but I dont have the source code now. I want to debug this two values ID = Request("EmployeeNo") and
Password = Request("PASSWORD"). I am not familiar with ASP

Comment: Is it possible for you to make changes in the ASP code on the server? I'm assuming test server.

Comment: @FleminAdambukulam Yes, I do.

Comment: I suppose returning values through Response.Write should do the trick. Something like Response.Write(ID). This should be before the IF condition. This way you know if the POST request is sending the data correctly. If yes, then there's probably something wrong with if conditions. Return the data from database and see if the password is the same. Its probably changed. Basically, return meaningful responses using Response.Write() for you to debug

Comment: @FleminAdambukulam I did use Response.Write(ID) and Response.Write(Password). When i use POSTMAN application to do POST request I can the correct response/output. But when I try t run php file it does not get any response using the curl method. How do i solve this? I checked my php using phpinfo() and curl is enabled

Comment: ok. I google abit and found this line to debug cURL. $errors = curl_error($ch);
    $response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); Now i am receiving this message => string(67) "Failed to connect to bonia.no-ip.info port 8181: Connection refused" int(0) ... how do i solve it? It seems to work when i make POST request with POSTMAN application

Comment: @FleminAdambukulam Any help?

Comment: Looks like the server is not up or the port is not accesible. Somethings wrong with the server. Won't be able to help as there's very little info